# How to show a preview of the line I'm drawing with QPainter in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

My code is drawing lines on a QImage using mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. It works fine but I would like a dynamic preview line to appear when I'm drawing the said line (ie on MouseMoveEvent). Right now the line just appears when I release the left mouse button and I can't see what I'm drawing.

I want the preview of the line to appear and update as I move my mouse, and only "fixate" when I release the left mouse button. Exactly like the MS Paint Line tool : https://youtu.be/YIw9ybdoM6o?t=207

Here is my code (it is derived from the Scribble Example):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter, QPen, QColor, qRgb
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
import sys

class DrawingArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DrawingArea, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StaticContents)
        self.scribbling = False
        self.myPenWidth = 1
        self.myPenColor = QColor('#000000') 
        self.image = QImage()
        self.startPoint = QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPoint = event.pos()
            self.scribbling = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.scribbling:
            self.drawLineTo(event.pos())
            self.scribbling = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        dirtyRect = event.rect()
        painter.drawImage(dirtyRect, self.image, dirtyRect)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if self.width() > self.image.width() or self.height() > self.image.height():
            newWidth = max(self.width() + 128, self.image.width())
            newHeight = max(self.height() + 128, self.image.height())
            self.resizeImage(self.image, QSize(newWidth, newHeight))
            self.update()

        super(DrawingArea, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def drawLineTo(self, endPoint):
        painter = QPainter(self.image)
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawLine(self.startPoint, endPoint)

        rad = self.myPenWidth / 2 + 2
        self.update(QRect(self.startPoint, endPoint).normalized().adjusted(-rad, -rad, +rad, +rad))

    def resizeImage(self, image, newSize):
        if image.size() == newSize:
            return

        newImage = QImage(newSize, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        newImage.fill(qRgb(255, 255, 255))
        painter = QPainter(newImage)
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), image)
        self.image = newImage


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(DrawingArea())
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can't figure out how to show the preview of the line I'm drawing and I haven't found a suitable answer yet. How can I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the lines just within the `paintEvent()` method instead than directly on the image, then paint on the image when the mouse is actually released.

```
class DrawingArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DrawingArea, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StaticContents)
        self.scribbling = False
        self.myPenWidth = 1
        self.myPenColor = QColor('#000000') 
        self.image = QImage()
        self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.startPoint:
            self.endPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.startPoint and self.endPoint:
            self.updateImage()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        dirtyRect = event.rect()
        painter.drawImage(dirtyRect, self.image, dirtyRect)
        if self.startPoint and self.endPoint:
            painter.drawLine(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def updateImage(self):
        if self.startPoint and self.endPoint:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)
            painter.end()
            self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
            self.update()
```

Note that you don't need to call `update()` within the resize event, as it's automatically called.

I also removed the unnecessary update rect calls, as it's almost useless in this case: specifying a rectangle in which the update should happen is usually done when *very* complex widgets are drawn (especially when lots of computations are executed to correctly draw everything and only a small part of the widget actually needs updates). In your case, it's almost more time consuming to compute the actual update rectangle than painting all the contents of the widget.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works perfectly, and for the precision regarding the unnecessary bits of the code, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this page](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/custom-widgets/bitmap-graphics/) shows some really nice solutions for the problem of yours. For example, it shows how to implement a custom class which actually gives you a "drawing board":

```
class Canvas(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 300)
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#000000')

    def set_pen_color(self, c):
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None:  # First event.
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return  # Ignore the first time.

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(1)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        painter.end()
        self.update()

        # Update the origin for next time.
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None
```

You can use this Canvas class (or whatever name you would give it) everywhere you need. For example in the MainWindow:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.canvas.set_pen_color('#fffee5')  # set the colour you want

        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.show()
```

Hope this could help! Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andris, I already came across this website. I'm sorry if I have not made myself sufficiently clear but I'm not looking for a way to "scribble" on a canvas but rather to show a preview of the straight line I'm drawing using the drawLine function of QPainter. It would look like the MS Paint line tool : [link](https://youtu.be/YIw9ybdoM6o?t=207)

Comment: @MrKartofel Okay, sorry, it is possible that I misunderstood your question. Thanks for clarification!